# Is there a way to delete an object passed to a function `foo (new Object())`?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, memory-management

I have been searching for this all day. So, in `C++` if you have this code:

```
#include <iostream>                                                                                                       

struct a {
    int x, y;
    a (int aa = 0, int bb = 0) : x{aa}, y{bb} {
    }
};

void printit (a*);
int main (void) {
    printit (new a {1,3});
    return 0;
}

void printit (a *aa) {
    std::cout << aa->x << " - " << aa->y;
}
```

If I am given `printit ()` function (meaning I have no access to `printit()` code) and `printit()` does not delete the object, is there a way that I can delete an object I have created?

```
printit (new a {1,3}); // <--- this object
```

To clarify, my question is how do I do above without having additional variable and make sure that object created have been deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I am given printit () function (meaning I have no access to
>   printit() code) and printit() does not delete the object, is there a
>   way that I can delete an object I have created?

The only way to get printit() to delete the object is to modify printit()'s implementation.

If you aren't allowed to modify printit()'s implementation, you could always make your own wrapper function and call that instead:

```
void printitanddeleteit(a *aa)
{
   printit(aa);
   delete aa;
}
```

... as a style note, though:  it's usually a good idea to keep the `new` and `delete` calls together in the same function as much as possible, since if you spread them around across different functions you will soon forget who is supposed to be deleting what, when, and then bugs will creep in and make your life miserable.

Also I want to second what songyuanyao recommended:  If at all possible, use smart-pointers when dealing with the heap, because then it becomes impossible to forget to call `delete`, or call it at the wrong time, since you simply never have to call it at all.

Comment: LOL, I ended up using your solution, just because it was required to minimize `std` library use. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 6):

You could ask help from smart pointers. e.g.

```
printIt(std::make_unique<a>(1,3).get());
```

or

```
printIt(std::unique_ptr<a>(new a{1,3}).get());
```

Otherwise, you have to save the pointer in a named variable and `delete` it later.

Comment: May I just ask is there a difference in these two?

Comment: @Gox Same effect here. We should prefer to the 1st one.

Comment: @Gox For more information see [here](https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/29/gotw-89-solution-smart-pointers/).

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. I accepted your answer because it is closest to what I was looking for but I did go with wrapper function from jeremy's friesner's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Better than

```
a* b = new a {1, 3};
printit(b);
delete b;
```

You can simply do:

```
a b{1, 3};
printIt(&b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the object to a pointer variable, and pass that to `printit`. Then you can delete it.

```
a *temp = new a {1, 3};
printit(temp);
delete temp;
```